# Model validation in Asp.Net Core before making an Ajax call from java script

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Below is the sample code, i am calling this code on button click event. My question is, can i validate my viewmodel object before making ajax call? i can see model errors in java script, not sure how to check.
My **viewmodel** class properties has Data Annotation Validator Attributes. I don't want make ajax call if the viewmodel is not valid, want to check (ModelState.IsValid) in java script code, before making ajax call.
Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        var viewModelobject = {};
        viewModelobject.Name = $("#txtName").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
            data: viewModelobject,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hello")
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, Anil, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd likely be easier to read this if your JavaScript were formatted as a block of code. You can do this by using three backtick (```) symbols before and after your code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` is server side code.Browser has no idea about what it is,so you could not validate `ModelState` in client side. You can use `Jquery Validation` at client side.

Here is a working demo:

1.Model:

```
public class UserModel
{      
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model UserModel
<form id="frmContact">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" id="txtName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnGet">Click</button>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    @*you could also add this partial view*@
    @*@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}*@ 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnGet').click(function () {
                if ($("#frmContact").valid()) {
                    $('#frmContact').submit();
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#frmContact").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var viewModelobject = {};
                viewModelobject.Name = $("#txtName").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify(viewModelobject),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello")
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AjaxMethod([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        return Json(user);
    }
}
```

*Result:*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please use jQuery form validation as shown below inside the button click callback:

```html
var form = $('form[name="' + formName + '"]');
form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
  //Do something if the form is valid
} 
else {
  //Show validation error messages if the form is in-valid
}
```